# How can I quickly lose all my stuff to talk to the Pope?

Tags: bead-machine-punktasia

When going for a walk, eventually you run into the Pope.  He asks that you:

> Come see me when you have given away all of your posessions.

This is a problem since I have millions of dollars and beads.  How can I quickly get rid of all my things?

Comment: I know you can attach a sink to your machine, and that means it gets wasted.  Or block off the outputs.

Comment: Uh oh, Pope's coming, better ditch that sword...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you meet the pope, you need to have planned on meeting the pope.  If you have too much stuff to get rid of it quickly, just restart.  (Note that you can quickly dispose of huge amounts of cash by using the vending machine - just be sure to stop your production immediately when you've saved up for the next upgrade.)

After you pass the pope the first time, you get access to the Quest, which soon results in you getting access to Puzzlers.  Puzzlers can be used to reverse your income from positive to negative, making it much easier to get rid of your stuff.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [developer](http://www.reddit.com/r/incremental_games/comments/20g5yc/bead_machine_machine_building_incremental_game/chowwns):

> v1.15 is out. Bribe the Pope for one BILLION dollars (at least for your first time past the Pope).

So, don't give away all your stuff.  Just give him a billion dollars.

Comment: What about any visit after the first?

Comment: Reading some more, it seems that the amount required varies based on your playtime.  A billion is the cheapest he will take, but will go up depending on how long you've played.

Comment: So what is the formula so I can tell how much money I would need for any given time.

Comment: 1 billion dollars if you don't have factories, 1 trillion dollars after that.

Comment: (But it's probably easier to create a string of Uncoilers and then Shuffle it and use Puzzlers for positive & negative output and Sink the positive output, giving an automated random negative drain on all your resources at once.)

Comment: once you have an easy way to make and lose resources the achievement is 10 enlightment.