# Bead Machine - 2nd Pope

Tags: bead-machine-punktasia

You can bribe the first pope by having at least $1B. 
What do you need to do to get past the pope the second time around?

Comment: "the amount required varies based on your playtime. A billion is the cheapest he will take, but will go up depending on how long you've played" - [comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172975/how-can-i-quickly-lose-all-my-stuff-to-talk-to-the-pope#comment234045_172981)

Answer (score 0):

1 trillion for the second, third and forth, not sure about the last one however